# Symfony 4 | ManyToMany Relation - Could not determine access type for property

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, many-to-many

**Hello everyone,**

I am currently working on a project on Symfony 4.
I have a ManyToMany relation between two doctrine entities (Groupe and Contact) , however when I"m trying to create a new contact I have the following error:
(I emphasize that the entities were created with make: entity). 
thank you in advance for your help.

**Exceptions :
Could not determine access type for property "groupe" in class "App\Entity\Contact": The property "groupe" in class "App\Entity\Contact" can be defined with the methods "addGroupe()", "removeGroupe()" but the new value must be an array or an instance of \Traversable, "App\Entity\Groupe" given.**

//**Contact.php**

```
 namespace App\Entity;

 use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
 use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
 use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
 use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

 /**
  * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\ContactRepository")
  * @ORM\Table(name="cm_f_contact")
  */

 class Contact
 {
  // .....

  /**
   * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Groupe", inversedBy="contacts")
   * @Assert\Valid
   */
   private $groupe;


   public function __construct()
   {
     $this->groupe = new ArrayCollection();
   }


   /**
    * @return Collection|Groupe[]
    */
   public function getGroupe(): Collection
   {
     return $this->groupe;
   }

   public function addGroupe(Groupe $groupe): self
   {
     if (!$this->groupe->contains($groupe)) {
        $this->groupe[] = $groupe;
     }

    return $this;
   }

   public function removeGroupe(Groupe $groupe): self
   {
     if ($this->groupe->contains($groupe)) {
        $this->groupe->removeElement($groupe);
     }

    return $this;
   }
}
```

//**Groupe.php**

```
  namespace App\Entity;

  use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
  use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
  use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
  use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;


  /**
   * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\GroupeRepository")
   * @ORM\Table(name="cm_f_group")
   */

   class Groupe
   {

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Contact", mappedBy="groupe")
     */
    private $contacts;


    public function __construct()
    {
     $this->contacts = new ArrayCollection();
    }

   /**
    * @return Collection|Contact[]
    */
   public function getContacts(): Collection
   {
     return $this->contacts;
   }

   public function addContact(Contact $contact): self
   {
     if (!$this->contacts->contains($contact)) {
        $this->contacts[] = $contact;
        $contact->addGroupe($this);
     }

    return $this;
   }

   public function removeContact(Contact $contact): self
   {
    if ($this->contacts->contains($contact)) {
        $this->contacts->removeElement($contact);
        $contact->removeGroupe($this);
    }

    return $this;
   }

}
```

//**ContactController.php**

```
 <?php

  namespace App\Controller;

  use App\Entity\Contact;
  use App\Form\ContactType;
  use App\Repository\ContactRepository;
  use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
  use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
  use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
  use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

  /**
   * @Route("/contact")
   */

   class ContactController extends AbstractController
   {

    //...

    /**
     * @Route("/new", name="contact_new", methods={"GET","POST"})
     */
     public function new(Request $request): Response
     {
      $contact = new Contact();
      $form = $this->createForm(ContactType::class, $contact);
      $form->handleRequest($request);

      if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {    
        $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $entityManager->persist($contact);
        $entityManager->flush();

        return $this->redirectToRoute('contact_index');
       }

      return $this->render('contact/new.html.twig', [
        'contact' => $contact,
        'form' => $form->createView(),
      ]);
    }
   }
```

**ContactType.php`**

```
    <?php

  namespace App\Form;

  use App\Entity\Contact;
  use App\Entity\Groupe;
  use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;
  use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
  use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
  use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

  class ContactType extends AbstractType
  {
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
     {
      $builder
        ->add('firstname')
        ->add('lastname')
        ->add('email')
        ->add('sms_no')
        ->add('birth_date')
        ->add('created_by')
        ->add('groupes', EntityType::class, [
            'class' => Groupe::class,
            'choice_label' => 'name',
        ])
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Contact::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Paste the ContactType form

Comment: It looks like this error comes from the form, which is not able to set groups as there is no `setGroupe(array $groups)` on contact. You have to create a DataMapper or add the method so the form works properly

Comment: Hi @AythaNzt below my ContactType                                                                  <?php

namespace App\Form;

use App\Entity\Groupe;

class ContactType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
        // ..
            ->add('groupe', EntityType::class, [
                'class' => Groupe::class,
                'choice_label' => 'name',
            ]);
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
     //..
    }
}

Comment: You can edit your post and paste it there for clarity next time :P

Comment: @AythaNzt lol sorry, it's done.

Answer (score 1):

Symfony Forms will use `get<Property>` and `set<Property>` to read and write the model data. In your case, since you don't have a `setGroupe()` method on Contact, the form does not know how to write the value back to the entity when you submit the form.

For this scenario Symfony Forms have [Data Mappers](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/data_mappers.html).

> Data mappers are responsible for reading and writing data from and into parent forms.

In your case you will propbably need something like this:

```
public function mapFormToData($forms, &$data)
{
    $forms = iterator_to_array($forms);
    // "groupe" is the name of the field in the ContactType form
    $groupe = $forms['groupe'];

    foreach ($groupe as $group) {
        // $data should be a Contact object
        $data->addGroup($group);
    }

    // ...Map remaining form fields to $data
}
```

Comment: Hi @dbrumann thank you for your answer. however, I have a question. since I generated my code with the make: crud command, is it normal that I have this error? I tell myself that the management of the update of the properties should be automatic.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with the MakerBundle, but it looks like this "normal" when using [`ManyToMany`-associations](https://github.com/symfony/maker-bundle/blob/master/src/Doctrine/RelationManyToMany.php#L40-L43) as they overwrite the setter. I am not sure if the resulting behavior with forms is intentional or an overlooked bug, but feel free to open an issue.

Comment: ok @dbrumann, thanks for your feedback. i'm going try your solution and I'll come back to you.